How to close a window on haxe / openfl / lime / flixel / neko
I want to make a function to close a program after pressing a button, but I don't know how to close the program. I use neko by the way.
I searched into the inter, but I didn't found anything that works or it only worked on flash or html5.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found a way to exit a program on lime.
First, you need to type:
import lime.system.System;

And then, on the line that you want to exit, Use:
System.exit(0);

The "(0)" means the time that the program wait to close.
